# Anyone try Magic Lantern Timelapse with a long lens?

Tags: timelapse

It’s really cool! I have used 4-5fps and 200-500mm. Aim it straight down a long road. I use an ND filter since the shutter is limited to longer intervals on a sunny day. Next try a busy beach, boardwalk and city sidewalk. Can I see what you have created?

Are there any techniques to make moving objects look sharper at mile long distances?

I have tried a fast shutter speed using a different mode, but then moving cars jump across the screen, sharp whenever you pause it, but not fluid.

Obviously I meant a long focal length sorry.

I am the original author of that part of the code in ML.

Comment: The title seems to imply that a zoom lens in necessary, while as best as I can read the body you did not change the focal length during shooting.  In that case a fixed focal length would work the same.  I suspect you mean a long focal length lens.  I also guess, without seeing the results, that you are finding that moving objects disappear.  This is a known technique that does not depend on a long focal length.  You want the moving objects to obstruct any background for a small fraction of the exposure time, so the background dominates the image.

Comment: This isn't a question that has "an answer" - This is more of a chatty question suitable for a forum or facebook group, voting to close.

Comment: Ross - that’s a wonderful idea! Moving objects disappear in a single capture when the exposure is upwards of 1 sec using ND filters. It’s difficult to combine these concepts with a Timelapse with 100’s of frames. I noticed objects moving across the frame disappear, while those moving parallel to the lense remain sharp.

Comment: How do I send a PM to Digital Lightcraft? I guess it’s not possible?

Comment: @SteveBright No, that's not possible. From your questions here, I think you have some misunderstandings as to what Stack Exchange is - I would encourage you to take some time and read the [Tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [Help Center](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Thank you. I understand it’s for questions. I’ve been reading and asking for 10 years. Will take the tour. Again.

Comment: What is my next step after asking my original question in question form? I didn’t see that in the Help Center.

Comment: This kind of "discussion" question is usually welcomed in chat. Once you have 50 rep, you can hop in there for things like that.

Comment: But it is a question! A question inviting discussion. Like every other question on here.

Comment: Questions DO NOT invite discussion. Questions invite **answers**.